# functional programming: Get list of data from nested loop

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have three class

```
class C {
  var id: String = _
}

class B {
  var c: List[C] = _
}

class A {
  var b: List[B] = _
}
```

I want to collect all "id" of class "C" instance, which are in a class "A" instance

```
val c1 = new C
c1.id = "data1"
val c2 = new C
c2.id = "data2"

val b = new B
b.c = c1::c2::Nil

val a = new A
a.b = b::Nil
```

Expected output for this sample code is List[String] having two element (ie, data1, data2)
In imperative programming, I have achieved same with below code snippet

```
def collectCId(a: A): List[String] = {
  var collect = List[String]()
  for(tmpb <- a.b){
    for(tmpc <- tmpb.c){
      collect = tmpc.id :: collect
    }
  }
  collect
}
```

How can I achieve same in functional way?

Scala Version: 2.11

Comment: The names of variables are confusing : `c` being a `List[C]`, maybe use `cs` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a for-comprehension:

```
def collectCId(a: A): List[String] = 
 for { 
   b <- a.b
   c <- b.c
 } yield c.id
```

Comment: thanks @chirlo. I have one quick question. Is removal of "var" is termed as functional programming in objective way?

Comment: @user811602 , could you rephrase the question? Not sure what you're asking, sorry.

Comment: When I can say that I have written code in Functional Programming Paradigm? Is there any fixed set of rule for same? I know that this can be different question in SO, but a quick link will help me a lot.

Comment: There are several concepts normally associated with FP, like avoid side effects  and immutability, but it's not all black and white, don't need to go all in. You can just use some FP principles in imperative programs and reap a lot of benefits. The [Wikipedia page on FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) has very good info to start with, and the [FPiS](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala) would be my recommendation to get deeper into it , just dont' read it all at once, keep reading on demand as you get more familiar with FP.